# How to save mongoose object using req.body

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to save an object to the database using mongoose express as:

```
 const data = req.body
 const product = await Product.create({ ...data });
```

but it an error show says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

even if the title exists in the data.

I don't want to write field by field like:

```
  await User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
    fieldX: req.body.fieldX
    ...
  })
```

is there any faster way, please?

Answer (score 0):

I am still a bit confused with the first part of your question; however, if you looking for a quicker way to add req.body values to an object then use ES6 javascript. Example below

1. Destructure your req.body

   ```
   const {username, password, fieldX } = req.body;
   ```
2. After destructuring, you can simply put the destructure item directly into the model

   ```
    await User.create({
     username,
     password,
     fieldX
   })
   ```

This will save you the time of defining all the keys in the object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am looking for something like User.save({...req.body})